# Can I hide a link in a Razor view, using a controller attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this code in one of the shard Views:

```
<li>
   <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Campaigns")" class="tables"><span>Campaigns</span></a>
</li>
```

On the Campaigns Controller I have a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` like this:

```
[AuthorizeRoles(Roles = "admin")]
public class CampaignsController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that if the user is not an `admin`, the link is still being rendered, even if the controller is not accessible.

I am using a custom implementation and because of this, standard methods of authorization such as `.IsInRole` will not work.

Is there a way to apply an attribute to my controller method in such a way that the link is hidden if the user does not have access, without using `.IsInRole`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do create your own extension method to extend MvcHtmlString so that Action thing will be rendered based on condition

```
public static MvcHtmlString IfAllowed(this MvcHtmlString action, bool allowed)
{
  return allowed? action:String.Empty;
}
```

When you use, I dont know how your custom stuff works but pass in the boolean based on your custom role or whatever

```
<li>
   @Html.ActionLink("Index","Champaigns").IfAllowed(true/false)
</li>
```